# Codename One Sockets Send Message to Client

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, socket.io, codenameone

i want to write a simple App for me (Android). For this it is necessary that the server can send data to my client (only one client at a time) but unfortunately i have no idea how to use sockets or websockets with codename one.
Can someone please post a small examplecode how to establish connection, listen on it and send some small data?

greetings

Captain

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the cn1lib from Steve Hannah to access websockets. Its available here: https://github.com/shannah/cn1-websockets

Found thru looking at https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html

Sockets are a bit problematic though, you might want to look at push, pubnub or just https if applicable. See the chat app demo parts 5 & 6 for the former:
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-5.html

Comment: Thank you i will take a look at it. I can't use push because i don't have pro and pnubnub seems like sending the data trough a dedicated server. I just want to use my App for myself in my own Wifi. HTTPS polls would be possible but no good practise. I installed the websockets yesterday but i wasn't able to figure out how to establishe a connection and didn't found the article you posted but the other using Tomcat. However, i will take a look at it later and commend again. Until then: Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok i took a look at it and for my case this isn't really helpful due to the fact that i want to write the server on my own. I just are not able to establish a connection with the websockets (the lib you talked about) so this problem istn't solved yet. Do you have some examplecode or other helpfull articles about the using of websockets?

Comment: Why is that not helpful? The example allows you to write any server you want? That is the web socket API. If you want regular sockets there is a cn1lib for that as well as builtin socket support.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this example code: https://towhidz.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/simple-chat-applicationclient-server-in-android/
Google is your friend

Comment: Codename One is the key phrase here. So the link seems incorrect